# Is it possible to add few more details like rich factor to the bar graph along with the pvalve?

Tags: r, ggplot2

| Pathway | #Proteins | Pvalue | Richfactor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peptide chain elongation | 90 | 1.11E-16 | 0.5 |
| Translation elongation | 79 | 1.11E-16 | 0.7 |
| P53 pathway | 50 | 1.11E-16 | 0.2 |
| cGAS sting pathway | 20 | 1.11E-16 | 0.4 |

The above given is the data. Using this data i tried to generate bar graph with pvalue and proteins but i want to add additional details to graph like Rich factor given in the data above.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

top_fun <- read.delim(file="Pathways.txt",header = TRUE)

topfun <- as.data.frame(top_fun)
#Turn your 'Name' column into a character vector
topfun$Pathway <- as.character(topfun$Pathway)
#Then turn it back into a factor with the levels in the correct order
topfun$Pathway<- factor(topfun$Pathway, levels=unique(topfun$Pathway))



ggplot(topfun,aes(x=Group,y=topfun$Proteins,fill=topfun$Pvalue)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge",width=0.4) +
  coord_flip() + scale_fill_viridis(option="mako")+
  facet_grid(Pathway~.)+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

Using the above code i generated this graph[image]

I want to add additional details like rich factor to the graph. Thanks for the help!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is to map `Richfactor` to the fill variable. You can add the p values directly as text, since they don't seem to be very helpful mapped to the fill scale, at least in this example

```r
ggplot(topfun,aes(x = 'WT', y = Proteins, fill = Richfactor)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.4, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_text(aes(y = 1, label = paste('p =', Pvalue), color = Pathway), 
                hjust = 0) +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "mako") +
  facet_grid(Pathway ~ .) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'black', 'white', 'black'),
                     guide = 'none')
```

[image]